# WHERE AND clause for the same column but different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

### Prior Information Notice

I have 3 tables:

types

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+
| id | category_id | name                  | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |           1 | T-Shirts              | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+------------+------------+
```

prototypes

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                    | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Gildan Softstyle Adult Ringspun T-shirt | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+
```

filters

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | name        | value               | extra | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 | gender      | male                | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | gender      | female              | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | age_group   | adult               | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | age_group   | child               | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 | age_group   | baby                | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

They are related one another through n-m relationship, so there are respective junction tables `types_prototypes`, `types_filters`, `prototypes_filters` as well. For more details please check also out my [dump file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/arsnie/eAGdz/types_prototypes_filters).

### Problem itself

I'm trying to set up filtering system (with Laravel), so I need to query all **Prototypes** that are related to all given **Filters** (logical **AND**). Until now I have managed to get the, as long as use chose only one **Filter**:

```
select * from `prototypes` 
inner join `types_prototypes` on `prototypes`.`id` = `types_prototypes`.`prototype_id` 
inner join `prototypes_filters` on `prototypes`.`id` = `prototypes_filters`.`prototype_id` 
inner join `filters` on `prototypes_filters`.`filter_id` = `filters`.`id` 
where `types_prototypes`.`type_id` = ? and `filter_id` = ? group by `prototypes`.`id`
```

The problem itself consists in the fact that this query is inapplicable, as soon as we have several filters that should be valid simultaneously:

```
...
where `types_prototypes`.`type_id` = ? and `filter_id` = ? and `filter_id` = ? group by `prototypes`.`id`
```

I know, `where ... and` doesn't work, because I have due to join only one column `filter_id` that can contain only one single value at the same time (what actually `groupBy()` takes care of). So in this sense I have a new one row for the relation of the same **Prototype** with another **Filter**, e.g.:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                    | created_at | updated_at | type_id | prototype_id | prototype_id | filter_id | id | name      | value | extra | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Gildan Softstyle Adult Ringspun T-shirt | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            1 |            1 |         1 |  1 | gender    | male  | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  1 | Gildan Softstyle Adult Ringspun T-shirt | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            1 |            1 |         3 |  3 | age_group | adult | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I have already tried several different methods, including `where 'filter_id' in(?,?)`, `where FIND_IN_SET('filter_id', '?,?')` and even restructured my database in accord with **EAV-pattern** (when the `filters` is divided into `filter_names` and `filter_values`). But every time I obtain only entries that fulfill one requirement of the whole set (equals logical **OR**), for instance (here we have prototypes for *adults* **and** *men*, but **not only** for *adult men*):

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                    | created_at | updated_at | type_id | prototype_id | prototype_id | filter_id | id | name      | value | extra | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Gildan Softstyle Adult Ringspun T-shirt | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            1 |            1 |         1 |  1 | gender    | male  | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | American Apparel Womans T-Shirt         | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            2 |            2 |         3 |  3 | age_group | adult | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | Gildan Adult Cotton T-shirt             | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            3 |            3 |         1 |  1 | gender    | male  | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | American Apparel Mens T-Shirt           | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            4 |            4 |         1 |  1 | gender    | male  | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 | American Apparel Kids T-Shirt           | NULL       | NULL       |       1 |            5 |            5 |         1 |  1 | gender    | male  | NULL  | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I'm almost desperate, does anybody have a clue?
Thanks you in advice for your help and sorry for so much text, I just wanted to describe all circumstances.

Comment: `and (`filter_id` = ? OR `filter_id` = ?)` The brackets are relevant

Comment: You mean something like in psedo-code--> WHERE (@FilterIDs IS NULL OR FilterIDs IN(@FilterIDs )) AND (@TypeIDs IS NULL OR TypeID IN(@TypeIds))?

Comment: @RiggsFolly in this case I'm getting entries for the first and second requirement, but not an entry that fulfills both entries simultaneously. E. g. I'm looking apparel for **adult men** and filtering with  **gender: male** and **age: adult**. But your way I'd also get apparel for **children men** (boys) and **adult women**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to join with the filters table repeatedly for each criterion.

```
select * from prototypes AS p

inner join types_prototypes AS tp1 on p.id = tp1.prototype_id 
inner join prototypes_filters AS pf1 on p.id = pf1.prototype_id 
inner join filters AS f1 on pf1.filter_id = f1.id

inner join types_prototypes AS tp2 on p.id = tp2.prototype_id 
inner join prototypes_filters AS pf2 on p.id = pf2.prototype_id 
inner join filters AS f2 on pf2.filter_id = f2.id

where tp1.type_id = ? and f1.filter_id = ? 
AND tp2.type_id = ? and f2.filter_id = ?
group by prototypes.id
```